# Why Docker CentOS container run 'echo $USER' shows nothing?

Tags: docker, centos

as seen in the picture,it shows nothing.Why?centos7.4.1708
[echo $USER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bymcl.png)

Comment: Why do you post a picture instead of copying/pasting text?

Comment: Also, in your screenshot, it doesn't show nothing -- it prints an empty line. That's a very different thing from nothing.

Comment: (Why an empty line? Probably because you're running this in an environment that doesn't have `USER` set, or which sourced a script or ran a function that overrode the prior value; but that's not something we can answer here without details on how to reproduce the specific environment).

Answer (score 2):

Your `$USER` environment variable is not defined. It is up to your shell to set this variable inside the container, and the one you are using isn't doing that. On a normal linux host, this is done as part of your login, but you do not perform a login with a container. You'll need to define the variable yourself or use a shell that has this feature.